# Local variables in MethodHandle

Tags: java, methodhandle

`java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle` and friends allow runtime code generation eligible for JIT via a series of [combinators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles.html).

How can I create *local variables* in MethodHandles?  Ideally, the method signature I want looks something like

```
MethodHandle withLocalVariable(
    Class<?> varClazz, Function<VarHandle, MethodHandle> usingVar)
```

though I'm not sure `VarHandle` is actually quite the right abstraction.

Note that just creating a holder variable isn't quite good enough -- I want different invocations of the `MethodHandle` to use different variables.

Comment: Can you give an example to show how it would behave / how it would be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not create a local variable. If you want to use a value multiple times you could create a pass-through with `identity` and then copy the value using `permuteArguments` (or just use `permuteArguments` by itself if you can) e.g.:

```
MethodHandle start = identity(String.class);
MethodHandle sideEffect = lookup().findVirtual(PrintStream.class, "println", methodType(void.class, String.class)).bindTo(System.out);
MethodHandle result = collectArguments(start, 0, sideEffect); // sideEffect needs to return nothing
result = permuteArguments(result, methodType(String.class, String.class), 0, 0); // copy argument

System.out.println((String) result.invokeExact("Hello")); // Hello\nHello
```

Where the passed argument is used both as an argument to the side effect handle and as a return value. Essentially you can use the value multiple times.

But there's really no easy one-fits-all answer when it comes to method handles. Perhaps the best advice I can give is to try and *not* use them as much as possible. i.e. write a static method with the code you need and then use a method handle to that in a longer method handle chain.